# Laravel development on Windows 10 - node is not recognized

Tags: node.js, laravel, environment-variables, puppeteer, browsershot

Here is my problem, I am dealing with it for a days, and any help is greatly appreciated.

I am developing a project using Laravel, on a Windows 10. I have installed NodeJS, NPM works just as expected, and also when I check `node -v` through CMD or PowerShell it shows current version.

So, my environment variables are placed where it should be, and works properly.

But the problem is, whenever I try to use some package in Laravel that relies on node, it shows me "node is not recognized..." Examples that occur this problem are [spatie/browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot), [rialto-php/puphpeteer](https://github.com/rialto-php/puphpeteer), and many other that relies on puphpeteer or on node generally.

Once again, my environment variables are set, but maybe they are not provided to Laravel or something like that?

Any ideas about this..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the [Custom node and npm binaries](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot#custom-node-and-npm-binaries) (and following paragraphs) from the Browsershot github page?

Comment: @brombeer Most likely it is. Default paths in packages for unix systems are exposed

Comment: @brombeer sure I am. But even when I change it with a path to my nodejs locally folder, I get the same error but instead of "node is not..." I got "MY-CUSTOM-PATH is not..."